# Why is $\psi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\pi n^2x} = O(e^{-\pi x})$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

We define $\psi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\pi n^2x}$.

Why is it that $\psi(x) = O(e^{-\pi x})$

EDIT: As $ x \to \infty$

(big-oh-notation)

I think we can assume that x is positive.

I get that each term in the sum is smaller than $e^{-\pi x}$, but there are infinitely many terms, so how is this justified?

Comment: For $x\to +\infty$, or for $x \to 0^+$? (Hint: the asymptotics hold only for one of the two.)

Comment: It is supposed to be $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Good choice. Note $e^{-\pi n^2x} \leqslant e^{-\pi nx}$.

Comment: The series is an asymptotic series.  It may be truncated at any point to obtain an asymptotic estimate.  For example, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\pi n^2 x} = e^{-\pi x} + e^{-4\pi x} + O(e^{-9\pi x})$$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right; adding up infinitely many $O(f)$ terms needn't yield an $O(f)$ function.

However in this case the result does hold, and can be proven in a low-tech way. Hint:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2x}\le e^{-\pi x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\pi nx} $$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you mean $\psi(x)=_\infty O(x)$ and to prove it we have 
$$\left|\frac{e^{-\pi n^2x^2}}{x}\right|\le e^{-\pi n^2},\quad \forall x\ge1 $$
so the series
$$\sum_n \frac{e^{-\pi n^2x^2}}{x}$$
is uniformly convergent on the interval $[1,\infty)$ since the series $\sum_n   e^{-\pi n^2}$ is convergent hence
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_n \frac{e^{-\pi n^2x^2}}{x}=\sum_n \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{-\pi n^2x^2}}{x}=0$$
hence the result follows and more precisely we have
$$\psi(x)=_\infty o(x)$$

Comment: But it's trivial that, for $x \geq 1$, $0 \leq \sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 x} \leq \sum_n e^{-\pi n^2} \Rightarrow \sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 x} =_\infty O(1)$, so it's not exactly a revelation that $\sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 x} =_\infty o(x)$.  I don't see the point of this.